# Should one use androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView or android.widget.SearchView?

Tags: android, androidx, searchview, android-search

I am confused which version of `SearchView` I should use. The documentation for [`androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView) clearly states

> If you're developing your app for API level 11 and higher only, you
> should instead use the framework `android.widget.SearchView` class.

However I can't quite imagine that this is true or a good idea, as e.g. `android.widget.SearchView` from API level 11 might be different than e.g. the one from API level 29.
So, anyone knows why the official documentation recommends to use `android.widget.SearchView` instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`?

Comment: I prefer the support version. The support version receives more frequent updates than the built in one. The documentation was the same in the old support libraries. It seems that this sentence was written a lot of years ago.

Comment: thank you, that's also what I assumed.

Comment: which is the support version here? please reply

Comment: @VijayJangid The ones in the androidx namespace are the newer ones / support versions.